# Adding to a HashMap gives a NullPointerException

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have to use a HashMap in Java and I need to fill it with some value from an ArrayList that is picked randomly.

I'm filling the ArrayList properly and the code that I have takes a random number, n which is less than the size of the ArrayList, and I use that random value to access a spot in my ArrayList and store that to the HashMap. So here is my code to add to the HashMap as described above,

```
hash.put(index, strArr.get(n));
```

where hash is the name of the HashMap, index is just an int value, strArr is the ArrayList of strings that I'm taking the item from, and n is a random number.

This is giving me a NullPointerException and neither I nor three of my CS friends can see why. Please help, any step in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

So it was just because I didn't initialize my HashMap. Sorry for cluttering up the site I just started learning HashMaps earlier in the week. :)

Comment: w/o seeing anymore code, my best  guess would be that you have not **initialized your hashmap** :)

Comment: or strArr can be null.

Comment: can you please add some code here?

Comment: please share entire code of the class please

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly accept an answer whichever you think OK and you will gain reputation points and also who answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NullPointerException means that you are trying to operate on a non initialized object.
These are the possibilities:

1. hash is null
2. strArr is null
3. n >= strArr size

   Debug your code, and see what is null and should've been initialized.

Comment: (3) will cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException (not a NullPointerException) - [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)).

Answer (score 1):

> Point 1: You have not initialized your hashmap.

If you have not initialized your hashmap and trying to put the element inside hashmap definitely you will get NPE.

> Point 2: Your strArr is null

Same thing, here if your `strArr` is `null` and you are trying to access the element of **Nth** position definitely you will get NPE.

below code may be help you.

```
Map<Integer,String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();

strList.add("Apple");
strList.add("Mango");

for(int i=0;i<strList.size();i++)
 {
   hashMap.put(i, strList.get(i));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initailized object of `ArrayList` Class or object of `HashMap` Class?

```
 HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> hash = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
 ArrayList<Integer> array= new ArrayList<Integer>();
 array.add(30);
 hash.put(1, array);
```